# jQuery autocomplete UI- I'd like it to start the search onfocus without the user having to type anything

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQuery autocomplete UI - I'd like to start the search "onfocus" and immediately show the list of choices when the user tabs or clicks into the search field without the user having to type anything.

The default behavior seems to requires the user to enter a character or a down arrow to start the ball rolling and start the search and get the values even when I set the number of character required to zero.

```
$( "#contact" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'remote.php',
    minLength: 0
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 13):

A bit more complicated than Emmett's answer, but...

- Pops up list on focus even when box already contains text
- Avoids re-popping up list after clicking an item

Here it is:

```
var closing = false;

$('#contact').autocomplete({
    source: 'remote.php',
    minLength: 0,
    close: function()
    {
        // avoid double-pop-up issue
        closing = true;
        setTimeout(function() { closing = false; }, 300);
    }
})
.focus(function() {
    if (!closing)
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Comment: You can actually do it by just using the parameters of minLength and focus in autocomplete, without any further coding.  See the solution by androidmj.

Answer (score 7):

I found that this code was a little cleaner and element specific.

```
 $(<selector>).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            delay: 500,
            source: funcDataLookUp,
            open: function() { $(this).attr('state', 'open'); },
            close: function () { $(this).attr('state', 'closed'); }
        }).focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('state') != 'open') {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try binding the `focus` with autocomplete.

```
$("#contact").autocomplete({
        source: 'remote.php',
        minLength: 0
    }).bind('focus', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    });
```

Check out my sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKMyU/).

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#contact").focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    }
});
```

Make sure your autocomplete's `minLength` is 0.

Comment: it works a bit odd now. The dropdown now requires the selection to be selected with either the down arrow or with double click. A single click put the choice in the box but it doesn't stay when you move the mouse. Firefox or IE

Answer (score 4):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454280/447356) didn't exactly work for me because the autocomplete results box would pop back up once more after selecting the desired result. This was because the `.focus` method was executed before the `close:` event.

Additionally, according to the code in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454280/447356), once the box closed, it wouldn't open back up because the `closing` variable stayed `true` due to`close:` being executed after `.focus`.

**The following code resolved those two issues** (note the variable `closing` is set to false in the `close:` event):

```
var closing = false;

$(function() {$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: 'remote.php',
    minLength: 0,
    open: function(){
        closing=true; },
    close: function(){
        closing = false;
        }
})
    .focus(function(){
        if ((!closing) && ($(this).val() !== "")){
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

this solution not working for me, but this:

```
$('#contact').autocomplete({
source: 'remote.php',
minLength: 0
           }).focus(function(){
if (this.value == "")
$(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

works good (source: [jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-on-focus-show-default-drop-down))

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY actually suggests this method

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

```
$('.yourclass').autocomplete({
   minLength: 0
   ,source:['blah','andblahagain']
   ,focus: function() {
     $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
   },
});
```

basically you use minLength:0 and the focus event with a search for "".

Comment: A solution that uses only JQuery autocomplete's parameters.  The exact solution everyone should be looking for.